# Sync OneNote on Windows Phone 8, “error e00001ae”

Tags: onenote

I have an iPhone and Windows Phone, and use OneNote on the web as well. Syncing to the iPhone and Windows Phone was working fine; two weeks ago sync to both phones stopped working. On the web, I can see all my OneNote documents fine. I haven't changed any settings on my Microsoft account nor on the two phones. I am not making huge changes to the content which would lead to conflicts.

The error on the iPhone is "Can't sync section: Quick Notes (Error 0xE00001AE)" and on the Windows Phone is "We can't complete this task. Try again. Error code: e00001ae".

On the iPhone I have deleted and re-added the Microsoft account, whereafter it synced exactly once, before having the same problem again.

On the Windows Phone, I cannot delete and re-create the Microsoft account (can only delete other accounts such as Google) and I cannot delete and re-add the OneNote app (seems to be part of Windows, cannot delete it).

On the Windows Phone I went to Settings -> Applications -> Office -> Reset Office. Now all my notes are gone from the phone, but it still won't sync, with the same error.

What can I do to debug this problem or resolve it?

Comment: Were you editing the same OneNote document on multiple devices at the same time?

Comment: I wasn't making any changes on the iPhone, I'm sure of that, and the iPhone doesn't sync now too, with the same error. Maybe I was on the Windows Phone, I'm not sure, now I've reset Office on the Windows Phone and all notes are gone, so I think any "conflicts" should have been resolved, and I'm still getting the error, so I think conflicts are not the reason?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I went for, which is hardly really deserving of the word "solution", is that I realized that OneNote has the structure of

Notebooks -> Sections -> Pages

Synchronization happens independently for each Notebook. So I

1. created a new Notebook in the web
2. created new pages there
3. copy/pasted my content across

Of course the formatting was messed up, the history was gone, but the content was there, and the new notebook synced.

I just left the old notebook abandoned, unable to synchronize still to today.

If there were any other note taking app for Windows Phone (e.g. Google Drive) then I would happily use it. OneNote has  great UI on Windows Phone, but if it can't synchronize, then it's useless.

Comment: FYI, you should be able to simply copy the entire pages, rather than the content. At the least that should preserve formatting.

Comment: @indrek, thanks for the tip, that would have been great, do you know how to do that? I tried right-click "copy" on the web onenote, then going to the other notebook, then right-click in the column listing the pages but "paste" was greyed out, there was just "new page".

Comment: Interesting, it worked fine for me - right-clicking in the page list and selecting "Paste". Perhaps it's a browser issue? I use Edge myself. You could also try [one of the OneNote apps](http://www.onenote.com/download).

Answer (score 0):

A user with a same problem has [posted a solution](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_onenote-mso_amobile/cant-open-onenote-in-android-samsung-note-5/31ec3a24-e2c4-45ff-a134-50ea1cb2a655) that worked for him. You could try this too. I have performed some edits on his answer to suit your case.

> Ok, I have performed following steps to fix the problem:
>
> Browser:
>
> 1. Save/backup every page within my only note book.
> 2. Delete every page from note book.
>
> <s>Android:</s>*iPhone*
>
> 3. Open OneNote App.
> 4. Login with the Microsoft account.
> 5. It successfully sync and open the empty note book.
> 6. Do the same on Windows Phone.
>
> Browser:
>
> 6. Create all pages within the note book from backup.
>
> <s>Android:</s>*iPhone & Windows Mobile*
>
> 7. In OneNote, "Sync All" (standing at note book level).
>
> Now, everything working fine again.
>
> Note: I am very careful now in operations like rename/delete, i.e. I
>   am trying to make sure that I sync it after each major operation.
>   Thanks.